# APEX Test Class Failing

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to deactivate this trigger but the test class is erroring and it wont let me deploy. Its showing this error:

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected:
>   0035E000008yLU5QAM, Actual: null
>
> Class.TestDeduper.testDupes: line 19, column 1

The Trigger is:

```
// Populate a Contact Lookup field if there's a dupe!
trigger DetectDupes on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    for (Lead l : Trigger.new) {
        if (l.Email != null) {
            String leadEmail = l.Email;
            List<Contact> dupeContacts = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Email = :l.Email];
            if (dupeContacts.size() > 0) {
                l.Dupe_Contact__c = dupeContacts[0].Id;
            } else {
                l.Dupe_Contact__c = null;
            }
        } else {
            l.Dupe_Contact__c = null;
        }  
    }
}
```

The test case is:

```
static testMethod void testDupes() {
    // Principle #1: Create records from scratch!
    Contact dupeContact  = new Contact();
    dupeContact.LastName = 'Spiderman';
    dupeContact.Email    = 'spiderman@gmail.com';
    insert dupeContact;            

    Lead dupeLead = new Lead();
    dupeLead.FirstName = 'Peter';
    dupeLead.LastName  = 'Parker';
    dupeLead.Company   = 'Daily Bugle';
    dupeLead.Email     = 'spiderman@gmail.com';
    insert dupeLead;

    // Principle #2: Use System.assertEquals()
    dupeLead = [SELECT Id, Dupe_Contact__c FROM Lead WHERE Email = :dupeLead.Email LIMIT 1];
    System.assertEquals(dupeContact.Id, dupeLead.Dupe_Contact__c);

    // Principle #3: Test things that shouldn't work!
    Lead uniqueLead = new Lead();
    uniqueLead.LastName = 'Xavier';
    uniqueLead.Company  = 'X-Men';
    uniqueLead.Email    = 'theprofessor@xmen.com';
    insert uniqueLead;

    uniqueLead = [SELECT Id, Dupe_Contact__c FROM Lead WHERE Email = :uniqueLead.Email LIMIT 1];
    System.assertEquals(null, uniqueLead.Dupe_Contact__c);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried swapping :dupeLead.Email with :dupeLead.Id?

Comment: Your trigger is not properly bulkified...no query in a loop is trigger basics 101.

Comment: Similar to - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94918/raise-code-coverage-by-replacing-outdated-code-in-sandbox - If you do not want the code anymore just delete it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you got this error after running all test classes in deployment process.

Your trigger `DetectDupes`  updates the `Dupe_Contact__c` field of lead with id of matched contact. However you deactivate this trigger, this field will store `null` value.

Therefore to skip this error you have two options

- **Change your assertion statement in your test class**. Deploy this using the same change set and rull all test classes. Like,

  `System.assertEquals('spiderman@gmail.com', dupeLead.Email);`
- You can **run selective test classes** only which are required to cover the classes and triggers contained in your change set. However, all your trigger or classes need to have atleast 75% code coverage.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense, the "uniqueLead.Email" is showing me that the variable does not exist when i try and save the class

Comment: I have updated my assertion statement. It will now work.

Comment: Typically I would say **Do not update the assertion**, it is doing what it is supposed to. thats like having someone always tell you what you want to hear even if it is not correct. - However in this case I would say it is appropriate. To the OP just do not think it is "normally" ok to just willy nilly modify assertions just to make them fit what you want.